# Append <text> to <svg> via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am studying SVG and have a very simple question that I am really struggling with.
How to append text to a svg tag?
I want to achieve the following result:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hl27.jpg)

I am doing this:

```
svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", width / 2)
        .attr("y", height - marginBottom / 1 * 2 )
        .text("text 2")
        .attr("fill","#808080")
        .attr("text-anchor","middle")
        .css("font-size", "14px");
```

But the browser shows an Error:

> Uncaught TypeError:
>   svg.append(...).attr(...).attr(...).text(...).attr(...).attr(...).css
>   is not a function.

But at the same time for `<line>` `svg.append` works :

```
svg.append("line")
     .attr("y1", height - marginBottom / 3 * 2 )
     .attr("y2", height - marginBottom / 3 * 2 )
     .attr("x1", marginLeft / 3 * 2 )
     .attr("x2", width - 20 )
     .attr("stroke-width", 1)
     .attr("stroke", "#5A97C3");
```

Please help me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error explains: there's no function named `css`, I think you meant `style`:  `svg.style("font-size", "14px");`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can put the SVG into a container (e.g. a div) and add the text elements inside the div. Example:

```css
#myDiv{position:relative;width:200px;color:yellow;border:1px solid green;}
.abs{position:absolute;}
#innerDiv1{top:0;left:0px;width:90px;height:15px;border:1px solid purple;}
#innerDiv2{bottom:10px;left:20%;}
.rotate {-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <img id="mySvg" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
  <div id="innerDiv1" class="abs rotate">Text One</div>
  <div id="innerDiv2" class="abs">Text Two</div>
</div>
```

---

Rotated text is wonky in my demo, but I'll leave that as an exercise if the concept is acceptable.